# UnivariateSpline Spline Interpolation behaving erratically

Tags: programming, fixed-income, interpolation

I am using univariate spline to interpolate betweeen a number of dots I have (in blue - it is a yield curve). The code is the following:

```
a = originalVals['Ttm'].to_numpy()
b = originalVals['YTM'].to_numpy()
spline = UnivariateSpline(a, b, s=5)

for i in range(0,100):
    spline.set_smoothing_factor(0.05)
    y = spline(bondDatabase.iloc[i]['Ttm'])
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be working properly because what I get is the green line in the first image
[image]

rather than something more similar to the red line in the second image (hand drawn by me). The behaviour is erratic and very visibly wrong e.g. in the (0.5,0.75) section of the x-axis. I believe it may have to do with the number of knots so among other things I tried to use s=0 but that didn't work, then I used set_smoothing_factor to 0.05 but same thing.

[image]

What could be causing the problem? Thank you

Comment: Hi, just a wild guess: I see this quite often when interpolating interest rates. This happens if you have two observations too close together (speaking graphically) with different values. The spline tries to match them all, causing the sline function to swing excessively. If you have quite a few of these close observations, then it can easily cause your splite to oscillate..You can see this in the top-right of your pic.

Comment: If these observations are bond returns, why not using some Nelson-Siegel-Svenson method instead and eliminate outliers to obtain a smoother and perhaps more stable function?

Comment: Hi @T123 , thanks for your reply. That's interesting. However, these are indeed zero coupon yields, so I WANT the spline to pass by each one of the knots. Take the point at around x=0.67: the spline indeed goes through, it, but then why does it immediately move up and follow sort of a straight line?

Regarding Nelson Siegel: that would be my next try but I would need to research it as I have never studied it before and I believe it's a little more complex